# Managed bean not called on a4j:jsFunction

Tags: javascript, java, jsf-2, richfaces

I have a problem with a a4j:jsFunction (below the snippet) :

```
<a4j:jsFunction 
name="updateVal" 
render="panelViewStation" 
execute="@all" 
onbegin="alert('begin');" 
onbeforedomupdate="alert('onbeforedomupdate')" 
oncomplete="alert('complete');"
action="#{controller.aMethod}"  
actionListener="#{controller.anotherMethod}"
onerror="alert('error');">
    <a4j:param name="val" assignTo="#{controller.val}"/>
</a4j:jsFunction>
```

In my managed bean, I have these methods :

```
/** action method */
public Object aMethod() {
    return "something";
}   

/** action listener method */
public void anotherMethod(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    // do something
}

// get/setter for val
```

This method is called by another js function below :

```
function processSelectEvent(target) {
    alert(target.previousElementSibling.textContent);
    updateVal(target.previousElementSibling.textContent);
}
```

and finally this method is called by a autocomplete element

```
<rich:autocomplete id="stationId" minChars="3" var="station" inputClass="autoCompleteWidth300"  onselectitem="processSelectEvent(event.target);"
                   fetchValue="#{station.name}"
                   autocompleteMethod="#{controller.searchStations}"
                   mode="cachedAjax" required="true" autofill="false" layout="table">
```

Unfortunately, the feature is not as expected. 
When I select an element on the autocomplete list, the function processSelectEvent is called.
The js function "updateVal" is called, but only the "onbegin" javascript. 
Other attributes are not called (onbeforedomupdate, oncomplete, onerror) and the managed bean is not called too (action, actionListener).

Any idea to solve my problem ? Thx

Comment: Any errors in the console? What RichFaces version are you using?

Comment: @ Makhiel. I use RF4.   No error in the server console.   No error in a4j:logs. The only thing I saw is that the server send an partial update (<partial-response id="j_id1">) but on the other part of the page

Comment: @Makhiel I put a phase tracker, and all the phases are realized (no error during validation phase)

Answer (score 1):

Check, please, that `a4j:jsFunction` is inside a `form`.

> The component sends a request using the standard JSF mechanisms. Note
>   that this means a JSF form is required.

See also http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=jsFunction&skin=classic